can 1 metre threaded rods (m16 / m20) work as cantilever outside garden stairs?
I have a 3-5m garden wall around the back of my house (roughly 40cm wide x 25cm high x 20cm thick brick blocks).
2.5m garden wall at the smallish height,
I was thinking if I got 1 metre m16/m20 steel rods (8.8 grade) and drill and insert 30-40cm of the rod into the wall and mortar them in place, fix with square washer and nut to the wall - 2 rods for each step (each runner) then a some timber for each step and getting u shape fixings, would this support someone standing on it ?  cantilever style.
I've been looking online and i see m16 8.8 grade can support 3000+kg but not I'm able to find the answer if there is 60-70cm of the rod out from the wall, what weight would it support at the furthest end of the rod ?

Please include a sketch with the dimensions.  Include everything you've mentioned.

It's also going to depend on the brick blocks themselves. Are they hollow or solid? If hollow, have they been filled with mortar? If not, do you want to be cantilevered off of a couple of thin layers of baked clay? Yeah, me neither. Review local codes & get a local engineer to help you design your project. Sounds cool, but cool doesn't override physics.

Stair projects have safety requirements that require either adherence to established construction methods or design and approval by a licensed engineer.  Your best path is to consult local tradesmen.

not really a answer, just stating the obvious

@Traveler -  The intent was to warn against danger, say why, and give direction to pursue his objective.  It wasn't so obvious to OP - obviously. ;)

Sometimes, @Traveler, the answer is to warn a person away from doing something potentially dangerous to himself.
